# Qlikview - Pivot Chart accumulation expression

Tags: pivot-table, qlikview

I am pretty new to Qlikview and I need some help with pivot table, accumulation expression (hope this makes any sense) over time. I have tried to find solution here, but simply by copy pasting expressions doesn't work (trial and error didn't pay off so far). So I hope you can help me with my first app.

I have managed to setup bar chart and it works perfectly because I can check the full accumulation, but in pivot there is no such thing..

Here is the setup:

Dimension: Date

Expressions:

Created = count(if(Status='New',Id))

Resolved = count(if(Status='Resolved',Id))

Open = Created - Resolved

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByhvhAQerbx6bm5WRGNfelNXRUE/view?usp=sharing) you will find sample data. This table was modified from original date in order to get "Event" list, where I can track when each ticket was created / resolved (thanks to the contributors from stack overflow). From my understanding this is a good practice.

[image: In attached image] 
In attached image you will see what I want to achieve, but it will probably cause issues with my totals. Right now, while Open is totaly broken, end total at the end of the pivot is calculated "Ok", but on each day its totally wrong. Can i have both? I would gladly give up on total sum of Open if I can get it to work daily.

I have personal edition so I am unable to open qlikview apps, so I would appreciate if you could show me how to do this in some detail.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone had issues with pivot accumulation like i had, use this expression:
    rangesum(before(count({}Id) - count({}Id),0, ColumnNo()))